# MySQLI prepared statement giving me strange results

Tags: php, mysqli

I just found out about mysqli prepared statements and I tried to do one myself and I am getting some strange results:

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "database");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `media`");

    $stmt->execute();

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }

?>
```

this returns `111111111111` I am expecting data from the database, I did a `print_r` on `$stmt` and it returns this: `mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => -1 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 0 [field_count] => 8 [errno] => 0 [error] => [sqlstate] => 00000 [id] => 1 )`

Please help, how do I get data from my database instead of ton of 1s?

UPDATE

I tried the following:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "losanihomesweb", "8tsy2esk", "losanihomesweb");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM `in-the-press`")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $col1, $col2);
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

I just get a blank white screen :( I do not understand how bind_results work, does it popular those variables on the fly?

Comment: [You should read the documentation on `fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), you're missing something in between `execute` and `fetch`, such as `bind_result`

Comment: If you decide to go with `bind_result`, you *must* use a definitive number of columns in your SELECT query (not the `*` operator), and they should match between the number of arguments in `bind_result`.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the `mysqli_stmt::fetch` function incorrectly. Here's the approach you should take:

```
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: This did not work, just a blank white screen, no errors

Comment: You kept everything before your old `$stmt->execute()` line, correct? You still need to prepare and execute the statement.